# MongoDB for Windows C#.Net Application

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

As I am starting a new product development in Windows Form C#.Net Application, I want to use Mongo DB with it.

Could anybody please let me know that can I use MongoDB database for Windows Form application ? and if yes, How about the reports (complex reports) and relation with them?

As I am new to MongoDB, I don't have any idea to integrate reports and relation with it.

Please let me so I can go further and take decision about database choice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MongoDB database for Windows Form application. Store your reports information in MongoDB's native BSON documents. For example each BSON document will stores one report. Use ids of documents for relations. As i found [samus](https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp) C# driver is fine. Check it;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question. You tagged it with mongodb-csharp, so you already seem to know there is a driver available for C# under Windows (which is also quite obvious if you check out the mongoDB page's driver section), so: yes, you can use mongoDB in a C# Windows application - there are even several other drivers available, like the ["official" C# driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center) or [NoRM](http://normproject.org/).

That being said, reporting is often considered to be a weakness of NoSQL databases, which is true if you need to aggregate data via complex queries. You might want to store data needed for reports in an "old-fashioned" relational database.